# How to get statistics from payment data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please look at the following source table:

```
transactionID    clientName    daysToPayment
--------------------------------------------
     1              A               10
     2              B               15
     3              B                5
     4              B                5
     5              A               20
```

To need to get some statistics out of this:

```
clientName    numberOfTransactions    totalDaysToPayment     averageDaysToPayment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A                  2                    30                       15                
    B                  3                    25                       8.3
```

Can somebody show me how to do this in one query (if possible)?

Comment: Do GROUP BY etc.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()`.

Comment: Since you don't know something this trivial, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in Ten Minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query

```
SELECT clientName, count(transactionID) numberOfTransactions,
SUM(daysToPayment) totalDaysToPayment, 
(SUM(daysToPayment)/count(transactionID)) averageDaysToPayment
from payment
GROUP BY clientName;
```

here the result output in sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eeb7d5/8